# Ruby About loops and string equality

Tags: ruby, loops, string-evaluation

***Why doesn't this work?***

```
puts "Hi"

x = "stop"

loop do
  a = STDIN.gets
  break if a.to_s.downcase.equal?x.to_s
end

puts "bye"
```

Comment: You don't need to use `to_s` for `a.to_s` or `x.to_s` as both are Strings and will always be, even when read from the keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `gets` will include the Enter key used at the end of whatever you type into it.

```
a = gets # I type in "stop"
a == "stop\n" #=> true
```

In order to fix this, [`chop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chop) off the newline

```
puts "Hi"

x = "stop"

loop do
  a = STDIN.gets.chop
  break if a.to_s.downcase == x.to_s
end

puts "bye"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons.

First `equal?` is a very strong form of equality: by default it's equivalent to comparing object ids, so two strings that have the same content but aren't the same object won't be equal. You probably want to use `==` instead

Secondly `gets` will include the newline that you typed which you can remove with `chop` or `chomp`